# onSaveInstanceState null pointer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-fragmentactivity

I get this error once in a blue moon and can't seem to reproduce it or find out what the issue is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial.BeerPage.onSaveInstanceState(BeerPage.java:221)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1933)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1642)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1710)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:524)
       at com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial.MainDrawer2.onSaveInstanceState(MainDrawer2.java:193)
       at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1253)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1229)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4175)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:174)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5731)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

BeerPage java code is:

```
public class BeerPage extends Fragment  {

    public BeerPage(){}

    String beerId = "";
    String breweryId = "";
    SearchView searchView;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beer_page, container, false);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.statsSpin);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.beerpage, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {


                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // do whatever stuff you wanna do here
                        Fragment Fragment_one;
                        FragmentManager man= getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
                        Fragment_one = new TasteTags2();
                        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
                        tran.addToBackStack(null);
                        tran.commit();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Fragment Fragment_two;
                        FragmentManager mantwo= getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction trantwo = mantwo.beginTransaction();
                        Fragment_two = new TasteNotePage();
                        trantwo.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_two);//tran.
                        trantwo.addToBackStack(null);
                        trantwo.commit();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Fragment Fragment_three;
                        FragmentManager manthree= getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction tranthree = manthree.beginTransaction();
                        Fragment_three = new FoodPairingsPage();
                        tranthree.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_three);//tran.
                        tranthree.addToBackStack(null);
                        tranthree.commit();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Fragment Fragment_four;
                        FragmentManager manfour= getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction tranfour = manfour.beginTransaction();
                        Fragment_four = new ListPage();
                        tranfour.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_four);//tran.
                        tranfour.addToBackStack(null);
                        tranfour.commit();
                        break;


                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });


        //body code goes here

        //get user information
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);
        final String beerId = prefs.getString("beerID", null);
        breweryId = prefs.getString("breweryID", null);
        final String breweryName = prefs.getString("breweryName", null);
        final String styleName = prefs.getString("styleName", null);
        final String beerName = prefs.getString("lastBeer", null);


        TextView bt = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.beerBreweryName);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do whatever stuff you wanna do here
                Fragment Fragment_one;
                FragmentManager man= getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
                Fragment_one = new BreweryPage2();




                ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(breweryName);


                //set beer to get style from
                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("breweryID",breweryId);
                editor.commit();

                tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
                tran.addToBackStack(null);
                tran.commit();

            }
        });


        TextView bt2 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.beerStyleName);
        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do whatever stuff you wanna do here

                ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(styleName);


                Fragment Fragment_two;
                FragmentManager man= getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();

                //set beer to get style from
                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("style",beerId);
                editor.commit();

                Fragment_two = new StylePage2();
                tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_two);//tran.
                tran.addToBackStack(null);
                tran.commit();



            }
        });



        String url = "myURL";


        new GetBeerDataJSON2(getActivity(), beerId).execute(url);


        //facebook stuff

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), null);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        return rootView;
    }

    //facebook stuff

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
                Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
                Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
            }
        });
    }






}
```

Comment: What is uiHelper actually doing? Seems like a really bad idea. It seems like you could very well be leaking contexts, and obviously it will be null if the fragment is created but `onCreateView` never gets called.

Comment: The docs say the `UiLifecycleHelper.onCreate()` should be called from `Fragment.onCreate()`. Where did you call it?

Comment: I think i didn't need these items in my fragment anywho. SHould be in my parent activity.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to move uiHelper instantiation in the onCreate callback, as the crash could come from the onSaveInstanceState called before onCreateView.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes if you not handle configuration change properly. So if your app not supporting multiple orientation ie  portrait and landscape both, you must specify orientation of each activity in manifest file.

```
        <activity
        android:name=".activity.ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />
```